# Why did LEM ascent stage swing during flight?

Tags: lunar-module, apollo-17

While watching Apollo 17 ascent footage, I've noticed that the camera is swinging quite a bit. It is definitely fixed to a window, so it means that the whole ascent stage is swinging back and forth during flight. I've spent some time trying to find an official explanation, but it seems like there are no mentions of the swinging in any flight journals/mission reports/etc. There's a small [note](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sts-471j-engineering-apollo-the-moon-project-as-a-complex-system-spring-2007/dc764168049ec675ce03cd2593d5743a_4_23_bennett.pdf#page=21) about 0.5 degree limit in one of the documents I've managed to find, but this swinging is definitely beyond -0.5 – 0.5 degree range. The footage is from a 16 mm movie camera with a 10 mm lens – [source](https://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/SearchPhotos/Metadata/Apollo17.htm). I suppose it could be due to the thrust vector being off-center, but there should be a better explanation.

[Apollo 17 ascent footage](https://youtu.be/Dr98RgNjAgg)

EDIT: changed the video link to a shorter version without excess footage. The swinging begins shortly after liftoff and is present during the whole duration of the footage. The author claims that the footage has been in their collection for a long time and there's no reason to fake it, but here's a more credible source – [Apollo 15 Video Library](https://history.nasa.gov/alsj/a15/video15.html#launch). In the "Return to Orbit" section you can find similar footage:

> Journal Text: 171:37:25   MPEG Video Clip: (1 minute; 1.9MB) by Mick
> Hyde.

The swinging is present during the whole ascent, but it's easier to see it after 00:43.

Comment: @uhoh oh, I definitely don't think that the moon landings were fake, I'm an liquid rocket propulsion engineer myself and couldn't be further from a conspiracy theorist. I just can't find any info describing the oscillation seen in the footage, so maybe someone here has an answer. It's not something dangerous since the missions were successful, but it seems kind of strange, especially compared to descent footage where this kind of oscillation is not present.

Comment: The descent engine is gimbaled and has continuous control; the ascent engine is fixed and attitude has to be adjusted via on-off pulses of the RCS thrusters. I don't know if that's the extent of the difference -- the bang-bang control may lead to fuel sloshing or something -- but I think it's the main driver, anyway.

Comment: @RussellBorogove yes, I thought that RCS thrusters are overcompensating for something, but I don't think it could be that bad. You might be right about the absence of oscillations during descent being because of the gimbaled engine, but I refuse to believe that RCS thrusters are that bad at attitude control. These are the same engines that were used for precise maneuvers during docking – LEM was the active vehicle during the second docking. So it's clear that RCS are precise enough to control the ascent stage without constantly overshooting. There should be a better explanation for this.

Comment: Could be something like using a much wider deadband rule during the ascent than during docking, conserving RCS propellant, since the trajectory didn't need to be particularly precise.

Comment: @radical_gale "but I refuse to believe that RCS thrusters are that bad at attitude control. " It depends solely on the deadband settings, etc. in the flight software.

Comment: This paper on the LEM autopilot shows constant (admittedly somewhat damped) oscillations with a period of a couple of seconds during ascent. Figure 14, page 12-14 (apologies for huge link) https://scholar.google.com/scholar_url?url=https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document%3Frepid%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf%26doi%3D1adebc9efbe342af333d777cf3a3e249f85c1574%23page%3D239&hl=en&sa=X&ei=t0NQZITHHqiI6rQPlL-HGA&scisig=AGlGAw8mc88-hkz_SLzCCRn_KrOh&oi=scholarr There's a discussion on the same page that may be of interest. It mentions slosh as did @RussellBorogove

Comment: @OrganicMarble it might be due to different deadband settings, but the [document](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sts-471j-engineering-apollo-the-moon-project-as-a-complex-system-spring-2007/dc764168049ec675ce03cd2593d5743a_4_23_bennett.pdf#page=21) I mentioned in the question states that there's a 0.5 degree steering limit. Maybe I didn't understand the sentence correctly, English isn't my first language. Correct me if the document is referring to something else.

Comment: @OrganicMarble interesting, looks like the oscillations seen in the footage. Propellant sloshing is definitely something I didn't think about. Thank you for the paper, I'll read it and write an update after. I'm curious why they didn't solve the problem and kept flying with these oscillations until Apollo 17. I guess it's not as dangerous as it looks.

Comment: @radical_gale Sure, great, no problem, and *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* Your quick edits following my now-deleted comment were perfect. I just gave some pointers to help avoid some folks from misinterpreting and downvoting or voting to close. Mission accomplished!

Comment: I suspect that the 'snap' from RCS bursts during ascent are related to the resulting non-gimbaled ascent engine thrust vectoring causes attitude to change more quickly. Smooth motions during docking using RCS pulses result because there is no main engine thrust interaction.